# Index view cant be found while existing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a AspNetCore.Mvc site hosted in Service Fabric Local Cluster. Mostly it works well but once in a while it doesnt find the index view. And this is with the index view not changed at all. After some resetting of the cluster and or trying with git clean and some other things it starts to work again. Im trying to figure out what is causing this.

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
 /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
 /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
 /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable<string> originalLocations)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<TFilter, TFilterAsync>()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Can you show us the file structure so we can ensure that the `Index.cshtml` file is in the right spot?

Comment: Regardless of wether its working or not for the moment the index file is always in the same place. Thats the main problem. Its never changed or reconfigured.

Comment: How about some code that shows us where you're trying to link/route to the index page? It must be a problem with your path or routing if the index file is never in a different spot